# Kill a windows application that has no process associated with it

Tags: windows-7, process

An autocompiler I attempted to close early ended up becoming dead instead of closing. Rather than kill it, I just ignored it and kept working. This happened again a few minutes later and I had two dead windows.

I went into task manager and killed cmd.exe, but it only removed one window. Now, clicking "go to process" on the dead window just gives me the first thing in the process list regardless of what it is.
So basically I have a dead cmd.exe window that doesn't actually have a cmd.exe attached to it, and have no idea how to kill it. Its been there for 3 days and its starting to get on my nerves.

EDIT: I've tried using Process Explorer and it just tells me it can't find the process.

Comment: I assume that Alt + F4 doesn't work? you can always just reboot. you can also try using Process Explorer. It allows you to identify a window with a drag and drop process, that may help you find the window handle, and if you can, then you can just close the handle. It is likely that the process is still running but hung, and you just can't see it in Task Manager anymore.

Comment: I tried process explorer, it couldn't find anything. I think I edited that in the moment you posted the comment :P

Comment: you are running procexp as admin, right? anyway, look at http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/ It may be able to find the window and the window handle, so you can close it. you can search for and close handles with procexp, or it looks like cmdow can do it with /END.

Comment: I used /t to find the windows' hex code, but when I tried to end it, nothing happened. CMDOW didn't throw any errors,  but the window didn't close. I'm starting to think rebooting may really be the only option here.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. It was in process explorer somewhere despite the drag and drop not detecting it. I found it after I looked at what the color coding meant and looked for suspended processes.

Comment: @code4240 - I was just going to say that.  A windows literally must have a process.  If it doesn't then its simply a graphical artifice, at which point, logging in and out of the user would clear it.  You can also close `explorer.exe` and restart `explorer.exe` in cases like this also.  There is no way to "hide" a process in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Process Explorer was able to find it. At first I didn't think it was working because the drag-and-drop function didn't pick it up, but I was able to find it by searching the list for suspended processes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent tookit from the systernals team wihin Microsoft called PSTools.  They have essentially ported the *nix ps toolkit to windows.

The particular tool within the toolkit that may be valuable to you is pskill.  Pskill can kill svchost.exe and even csrss security threads, it will bluescreen the system if you do kill csrss and I only note that to illiterate the power of the tool.  Perhaps it will kill your 'hung' cmd.exe or the name of the process that you were running within cmd.exe.

Here is the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) to the toolkit.

Comment: My issue is that there's no process to kill in the first place. CMD.exe is not running, and the process running through it (autocompiler.exe) does not exist either. The window is a ghost.

Answer (score 0):

When a window won't go away, it isn't always the fault of the process that own(ed) that window. It may be the fault of whatever process owns the stuff underneath the window. A process is not responsible for making its window go away (other than just calling DestroyWindow). Rather, the processes that own the windows that are supposed to be revealed are responsible for redrawing their windows themselves.

For example, Explorer (not IE, just explorer.exe) owns the desktop. Suppose some app has a window on your desktop, with nothing else underneath it but the desktop. If you click on the window's red X and the process calls DestroyWindow, Explorer is supposed to hear about it and redraw the part of the desktop that should be revealed. (Consider that the window that's going away has no idea, no way of knowing, what's under it... so it *can't* redraw that stuff.)

So: If the process (that has nothing under its window but the desktop) goes away but its window stays there, it usually means that Explorer is hung, or at least the Explorer thread that owns the desktop is. (Yes, the desktop is a window, it just lacks the usual decorations.)

A workaround is to use Task Manager to kill explorer.exe and start another one (from TM's File menu, Run.., explorer.exe). You might try that in this case.

Comment: Killing explorer didn't remove the window. It did remove everything else though.
This is strange because I can still move, minimize, and resize the window. I just can't close it.

Comment: In that case the thread that owns the window is still there and active (it's that thread's job to redraw it as it's moved). That one I don't have a quick cure for.